# Warning: set_time_limit() [function.set-time-limit]: Cannot set time limit in safe mode in

Tags: php, safe-mode

I have a large script that has a set_time_limit(0) directive to insure it processes fully.

However, I'm getting a few reports of this error on a small percentage of installations:

Warning: set_time_limit() [function.set-time-limit]: Cannot set time limit in safe mode...

Is there a method call to check for safe mode before committing the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a method call to check for safe mode before committing the function?

Yes, there is

```
ini_get('safe_mode')
```

> Whether to enable PHP's safe mode. If PHP is compiled with --enable-safe-mode then defaults to On, otherwise Off.
>
> [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode)

- [`ini_get()`](http://php.net/ini_get)

Comment: OK, looks like I should use: if(!ini_get('safe_mode')){set_time_limit(0);}

Comment: @RegEdit Yep. One note, safe_mode is deprecated in 5.3 (rumored to be removed in 6.0) but you should be safe either way. That warning is more intended for those trying to turn safe_mod ON.